# std::bind doesn't use the move constructor

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a class MyClass which has both a copy and move constructor. I try to send a MyClass object from one thread to another via a queue along with a functor. For this task, I use std::bind in the following manner:

```
someQueue.push( std::bind(
   [ this ]( MyClass & object ) { this->m_ObjectMember.addObject( object ); },
   std::move( localObject ) ) );

class MyClass
{
   public:
   MyClass( MyClass const& other );  <--- always called
   MyClass( MyClass && other );  <--- never called
   <...>
}
```

My problem now is that every time said std::bind is called the MyClass object (handed over via std::move( localObject ) is copied at least twice, I can see this from copy constructor call. I know that one call is from the construction of the MyClass object instance inside the functor returned by MyClass, however, since I hand over the object via std::move and the class has a move constructor, I would expect it to use the move constructor and leave the copy constructor alone. But in the end only the copy constructor is called.

Can someone tell me why and what I can do to save at least one copy?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't `std::bind`'s result that is being copied in the `push`? That would cause a copy of `MyClass`.

Comment: Please share a [MCVE]. It may be difficult to diagnose this problem without being able to reproduce it.

Comment: Inside the call stack, this is the function in frame 1 ( frame 0 is the copy constructor):                 template<typename _UHead>
        constexpr _Head_base(_UHead&& __h)
: _Head(std::forward<_UHead>(__h)) { }     Its from libc tuple header.

Comment: What is the point of using `std::bind` with a lambda?  Can't you just capture the object in the lambda itself?  `someQueue.push([this, object = std::move(localObject)]() { this->m_ObjectMember.addObject(object); });`  **EDIT**: Ahh, this requires C++14.

Comment: Hmm...is there still a hidden copy in this variant? Edit: Ok, I may only use 11.

Comment: template<typename _UHead>
 _Head_base(__uses_alloc0, _UHead&& __uhead)
: _M_head_impl(std::forward<_UHead>(__uhead)) { }

Comment: What is the type of `someQueue`?  Most likely you are seeing a copy because the object you create from `bind` is copied into the queue.

Comment: Can not mimic this behaviour `struct A{
    A() = default;
    A(A const&){std::cout << "copy" << std::endl;}
    A(A &&){std::cout << "move" << std::endl;}
};
int main(){
    A a;
    std::bind([](A &){},std::move(a))();
    return 0;
}`